Как исправить ошибку в ansible при загрузке файлов?
Пытаюсь загрузить файлы на удаленные машины с помощью ансибл через метод copy. Получаю ошибку
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Data could not be sent to remote host \"x.x.x.x\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh.

Все хосты доступны по ssh, могу к ним подключиться с этой машины. Модуль ping от ансибла ошибок не выдает.
Пробовал в ansible.cfg добавлять строки, но результат тот же.
transfer_method = smart
scp_if_ssh = smart

UPD
запуская руками команду scp обнаружил, что после определенного кол-ва файлов скорость закачки падает и вскоре соединение разрывается, с ансиблом та же история, уменьшив количество файлов все отлично грузится.

Решение, как всегда, простое и очевидное.
Проблема была в конфиге ssh, который при длительной загрузке разрывал соединение.
открываем /etc/ssh/sshd_config
увеличиваем лимиты на открытое соединение, к примеру:
ClientAliveInterval 1000
ClientAliveCountMax 3

перезагружаем сервис - sudo systemctl reload sshd
